# Can I execute makemigrations and migrate command in my PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I changed my project interpreter to `python 3.5`, and I still has used to in the terminal to execute the :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Because I have changed the project interpreter to `python 3.5`, I must use `python3 manage.py migrate` to realize that, sometimes I will write `python` rather than `python3`.

So is there a method in PyCharm to realize that?

Comment: Have a look at virtualenvs (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), that can solve your problems with having different python version installs.

Answer (score 3):

You can config the Run/Debug Configurations to do with that:

[image]

Then you can click the run button to execute it:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Because in the configurations you can set the Python Interpreter, so, by this reason can meet your expectations.